# Proving that $\operatorname{image}(T^2)$ = $\operatorname{image}(T)$ implies $\ker(T)$ = $\ker(T^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\newcommand{\image}{\operatorname{image}}$For an assignment, I have the prove the equivalence of 5 statements for a linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow V$:

a) $\image(T^2) = \image(T)$

b) $\ker(T) = \ker(T^2)$

c) $\image(T) \cap \ker(T) =$ {$0$}

d) $V = \image(T) \oplus \ker(T)$

e) $\ker(T_{\image(T)}) = $ {$0$}

So I try to assume a) is true and that implies b) is true. From $\image(T^2) = \image(T)$, I know I have to use the rank-nullity theorem to prove the kernel and that $\image(T^2) = \image(T)$ implies each $v \in V$ can be represented as a linear transformation of another vector in $V$. But I don't know how to make that connection and would appreciate some help.

Also can I have hints for $\ker(T_{\image(T)})$ means?

Comment: I suspect that $T_{\text{image}(T)}$ means the restriction $T|_{\text{image}(T)}$.

Comment: We are assuming a finite dimensional $V$, yes?

Comment: The piece you may be missing is that $\operatorname{image} T^2 \subseteq \operatorname{image} T$, and $\operatorname{ker} T \subseteq \operatorname{ker} T^2$. If you haven't seen this before, try proving it, then try using it to prove the equivalence.

Comment: yeah we are assuming it is finite dimensional

Answer (score 0):

(a) implies (e): Since $\operatorname{image}(T)=\operatorname{image}(T^2)$, $T|_{\operatorname{image}(T)}$ is an isomorphism. So its kernel is zero.

(e) implies (c): Suppose there is a vector $v\in\operatorname{image}(T)\cap\ker(T)$. Then $Tv=T|_{\operatorname{image}(T)}v=0$ implies $v=0$ (because $T|_{\operatorname{image}(T)}$ is an isomorphism).

(c) implies (d): You have assumed that $V$ is finite dimensional. Use rank-nullity theorem and count the dimensions.

(d) implies (b): Let $v$ be a vector with $T^2v=0$. I must show that $Tv=0$. Indeed, $T^2v=T(Tv)=0$ implies $Tv$ is in the kernel of $T$. But it is also in the image of $T$, so $V=\operatorname{image}(T)\oplus \ker T$ implies $Tv=0$.

Can you work for the other way round? Hint: use duality.

Comment: @RyanZhou Since $\dim\ker T+\dim \operatorname{image}(T)=\dim V$,$$\dim(\ker T + \operatorname{image}(T))=\dim\ker T+\dim \operatorname{image}(T)-\dim(\ker T + \operatorname{image}(T))=\dim V -\dim\{0\}$$ Now that $\ker T + \operatorname{image}(T)$ is the subspace of the finite dimensional $V$ with full dimension, it must be equal to $V$.